# Unable to access dependent modules in Django project deployed in Apache server

Tags: python, django, apache

I recently moved my Django project to Apache server. I am facing a few issues with respect to dependency modules being inaccessible after moving the project to Apache.

Here are my configuration files:

This is my bemoss.conf file in the sites-available directory of Apache:

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/kruthika/workspace/bemoss_web_ui
WSGIPythonPath /home/kruthika/workspace/rtunetwork/volttron
WSGIPythonPath  /home/kruthika/workspace/bemoss_web_ui/helper
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/kruthika/workspace/bemoss_web_ui/bemoss.wsgi
ServerName bemoss.com
Alias /static /home/kruthika/workspace/bemoss_web_ui/static
<Directory /home/kruthika/workspace/bemoss_web_ui/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my bemoss.wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/home/kruthika/workspace']+sys.path
print sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='bemoss_web_ui.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

My project is accessing a few more python files from another project. I added a reference to those in my .conf file above and in settings.py file as given below.

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print PROJECT_DIR

sys.path.insert(3,os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'ZMQHelper'))
sys.path.insert(1,os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'helper'))

sys.path.insert(2, '/home/kruthika/workspace/rtunetwork/volttron')
print sys.path
```

This is my project folder definition:

[image]

When I try to access a link, whose views.py file refers to the above mentioned dependencies, it throws a import module error as given below.

[image]

My question here is how to refer to my dependent modules/python classes so that the files are imported properly.

All these imports were working fine when I executed the project on Django's development server. Is there some Apache configuration I am missing or doing wrong? I am new to server configurations and I think I am missing something here.